# Fully update pie chart using ExtJS 4.2.0 and external datasource

Tags: extjs

I am currently creating a "drill-down" style pie chart, where clicking on a "slice" should update the pie chart with data within that slice.

Imagine for example an E-commerce report which shows sales by top level categories:

Shirts - $10,000
Pants - $8,000
Shoes - $3,500

Then clicking on the "Shirts" slice would display detailed information about sales in the Shirts category:

T-Shirts - $7,000
Polo Shirts - $2,000
Tank Tops - $1,000

I have a basic example here using a data source that returns random information:

http://jsfiddle.net/informationarchitech/BrMeh/

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

var level = 1;

Ext.define('Report', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'category',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'purchases',
        type: 'string'
    }],
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    id: 'store',
    model: 'Report',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://informationarchitech.com/demos/rand.php',
        reader: {
            root: 'content',
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 350,
    animate: true,
    store: store,
    series: [{
        listeners: {
            itemmousedown: function (obj) {
                level++;
                store.getProxy().url = 'http://informationarchitech.com/demos/rand.php?parent=' + obj.storeItem.data['category'] + '&level=' + level;
                store.load();
            }
        },
        type: 'pie',
        angleField: 'purchases',
        showInLegend: true,
        label: {
            field: 'category',
            display: 'rotate',
            contrast: true,
            font: '18px Arial'
        }
    }]
});
});
```

As you can see, clicking on a slice results in inconsistent behavior.  Sometimes it seems to update correctly, but often it seems to somehow be merging or overwriting the previous data.

I have tried every "clear," "update," "reset" method I can find, on the chart, the store, etc, and nothing I have tried seems to successfully "fully" update the pie chart with the new data.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?